# Analysis Services measure has no data

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I have an analysis services 2008 R2 cube that is not returning data for one of the measures.  The data source for the measure is a view that has multiple union statements.  I have other measures in the same cube that have views for a data source that are working fine.

When I exported the view into a table the cube was able to return data when i point the data source for the measure to the table.

I have checked that there is a partition for the measure, the Calculate statment in the code page for the cube is there.  The query that is run when processing the cube in MS SQL Profiler returns data.

Hopefully someone can help and tell me why the measure is not returning any data.  Thanks.

Comment: When you process the cube from BIDS or Management Studio, you can open some of the nodes in the dialog displaying the actions done for the fact table processing and will see the SQL sent by Analysis Services to the database. Do you see values in the measure column if you execute this statement in Management Studio against the database?

Comment: Hi. I found the problem. The data is pulled from views that check the user's login which is why no data was returned